# MMS video auto compression

Tags: video, mms

I have a new Samsung Galaxy Note 3.  I love the device, but sending a quick video MMS seems to be a challenge.

On other devices I have used, the video will automatically get compressed to a very low quality and will just send it.  This is all I want.  I don't need to send super clear video, just a small compressed video to family and friends.

Are there any apps that will handle this automatically without making me upload to a cloud service and sending a link or some cumbersome process?

I also don't want to have to choose a low quality recording beforehand, I would like the good quality stored on my phone, but send a simple low quality clip over the air.